# Excel conditional formatting row if cell starts with

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to format a row based off a cell within it.

My table runs from A6 to K207 and I want to highlight the row in bold if the cell in B6 starts with SA.

I tested my formula

```
=IF(LEFT(TRIM(B26),2)="SA","YES","NO")
```

in another cell and that works ok - but I can't get the formatting to work for some reason...

I removed the yes/no and placed into a conditional formatting rule applying to my whole table and it doesn't work. Even if I apply it to just a row it doesn't work.

Am I using if statements within conditional formatting right? I've looked on Google and here and have found similar issues but not the same one, they've all used set values/ranges but not a 'starts with' condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional formatting is an `IF` statement by default, and formats depending on whether the formula is `TRUE` or `FALSE` therefore an additional `IF` statement is not needed:

```
=LEFT($A6,2)="SA"
```

This will do the trick, apply this to the entire range as needed.

It will test whether all cells in column a start with "SA" and highlight that cell. If it is applied to a range including more columns, the $ sign fixes the column as A so tests that cell and highlights every cell based on that, effectively highlighting the entire row.

You can also use an `OR` statement to pass multiple arguments like so:

```
=OR(LEFT($A6,2)="SA",LEFT($A6,2)="BO")
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The OR statement was also a big help in understanding multiple 'ifs' on conditional formatting - a very big help as that was actually going to be my next tricky step to solve :)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO. When doing conditional formating (CF) in a formula, you need to apply references.

> **[Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)**

Right now your formula is `=IF(LEFT(TRIM(B26),2)="SA","YES","NO")`. You are using relative references, so the CF rule will check according to their position. In A6 it will check the value of A6, and I guess you would like the rule to check the value **always** in column B.

So the first fix you need in yor formula will be (it needs more, hold on)

```
=IF(LEFT(TRIM($B26),2)="SA","YES","NO")
```

Now, it will check always the value in column B. But we need to fix something else. To make the CF based on a formula, you need to formulate something that returns a **boolean** value, `True` or `False`. Your values `Yes` or `NO` are strings (text), not boolean, so they don't work.

So try this formula and let's see if it works:

```
=IF(LEFT(TRIM($B26),2)="SA",TRUE,FALSE)
```

An IF Functions allows you to make a question where the answer must be yes/no (true/false) and, depending of the answer, Excel will do an option or another.

With CF rule based on a formula, you just need the question itself, you don't need to choose an option. So the short version of this formula, as @Plutian states in his answer, is just doing:

```
=LEFT(TRIM($B26),2)="SA"
```

Try to adapt this to your needs.